# Deliberately slow down file access speed

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, filesystems

I am trying to deliberately slow down access to files on my Windows machine to test load times on an application I am making.

I've tried virtual machines and giving it limited CPU/RAM resources, but that doesn't quite do what I require.

Is there a way to slow down access to the virtual hard drive or to a folder etc?

VirtualBox/VMWare are both good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VirtualBox,

> Starting from version 4.0 we are able to limit Virtual Box bandwith
>   for acess to disk images (see [Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-bandwidth-limit) for details)
>
> We need to create a bandwith group first (in the example below named
>   "Limit" for 20 MB/s):
>
> ```
> VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" --name Limit --add disk --limit 20
> VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --storagectl "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd
>                                    --medium disk1.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
> VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd
>                                    --medium disk2.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
> ```
>
> **Note:** From versions >= 4.2 these commands changed to:
>
> ```
> VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" add Limit --type disk --limit 20M
> VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --controller "SATA" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd
>                                    --medium disk1.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
> VBoxManage storageattach "VM name" --controller "SATA" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd
>                                    --medium disk2.vdi --bandwidthgroup Limit
> ```
>
> We need to give the details of our personal setup above.
>
> To further limit disk access to 10 MB/s we can then issue
>
> ```
> VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" --name Limit --limit 10 # version 4.0
> VBoxManage bandwidthctl "VM name" set Limit --limit 10M   # >= 4.2
> ```
>
> This can even be done during runtime.

**Please note that all credit is due to the [original author on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116135/how-can-i-limit-disk-access-bandwidth-for-a-virtual-machine-guest).**